# Unable to load plugins; ClassLoader error

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, pluginlib, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a plugin to test some changes that I will make in the exploration algorithm later. But, I am unable to load the plugins which I created. When I run my launch file, it calls for this plugin, but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1446688037.439927809]: Failed to load exploration plugin! Error: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type NearestBasedAllocation as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

In my package.xml, I am using export tag to link to `frontier.xml`:

```
<export>
    <nav2d_navigator plugin="${prefix}/frontier.xml" />  
</export>
```

While in `frontier.xml`, I am giving a brief explanation about my class

```
<library path="libFrontierPlugins">
    <class name="NearestBasedAllocation" type="NearestBasedAllocation" base_class_type="ExplorationPlanner">
        <description>
            Performs simple, uncoordinated nearest-frontier exploration.
        </description>
    </class>
</library>
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(frontier_exploration)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
    geometry_msgs
    nav2d_navigator
    nav_msgs
    pluginlib
    roscpp
    visualization_msgs
    tf 
    std_msgs
)

catkin_package(LIBRARIES
    ExplorationPlugins
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    tf
    pluginlib
    geometry_msgs
    nav_msgs
    visualization_msgs
    nav2d_navigator
    std_msgs 
)

include_directories(include/${PROJECT_NAME}/${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(FrontierPlugins src/NearestBasedAllocation.cpp)
add_dependencies(FrontierPlugins ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(FrontierPlugins ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS FrontierPlugins  
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})

install(FILES frontier.xml  
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

Can anyone please help me with the reason why I am unable to load these plugins?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220454/unable-to-load-plugins;-classloader-error/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I am sure you have figured out the answer to this, just to make sure that others are able to find the answer easily here is what is causing the issue.

**Registering/Exporting a Plugin**

In order to allow a class to be dynamically loaded, it must be marked as an exported class. This is done through the special macro `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS`. This macro can be put into any source (`.cpp`) file that composes the plugin library, but is usually put at the end of the .cpp file for the exported class. For the example above, we might create a `class_list.cpp` file in package `example_pkg` that looks as follows and compile it into the `librectangle` library. In your case your cpp should have something like this at the top

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <FrontierPlugins/NearestBasedAllocation.h>

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(FrontierPlugins::NearestBasedAllocation, YourBaseClassNamespace::YourBaseClass)
```

---

Originally posted by [jclinton830](https://answers.ros.org/users/38971/jclinton830/) with karma: 91 on 2019-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0